# Is '(A)' a keyword?

Tags: fortran, keyword

I have a doubt about Fortran code. Is "A" a keyword? I found this character used in write and format commands but I can't find some specific documentation about it. Here are some examples:

```
CHARACTER *10  name
write(*,1) name
1 format   ("   Your name is ",A)
```

or

```
end = LNBLNK(string)
write(4,'(A)') string(1:end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `A` is an *data edit descriptor* for character string output. For more read some textbook about Fortran I/O or a tutorial like https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/format.html

And it the second code sample, `A` is not even in a position where a keyword would be used. `'(A)'` is a normal string, like `'Hello world'` or `"   Your name is "`, for example. But here the content of the string and where the string is used is what matters. It contains a descriptor and it is used as a *format string* in the write statement.

In the FORMAT statement it is not a normal string, but a special syntax, but it works the same.